# Bitcoin address convert to RIPEMD160

Tags: python, hex

Why the result is not saved RIPEMD160.txt gives an error
I can see on the processor that the code is working but the file is empty
I always get the same
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
import base58

with open('addresses.txt', 'r') as f, \
     open('RIPEMD160.txt', 'a') as i:
   for addr in f:
       addr = base58.b58decode_check(addr).encode('hex')[2:]
      
def decode(addr):

     b58 = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

     def base58_to_dec(addr):
        dec = 0
        for i in range(len(addr)):
            dec = int(dec * 58 + b58.index(addr[i]))
        return(dec)

     def dec_to_byte(dec):
        out = ''
        while dec != 0:
            remn = mpf(dec % 256)
            dec = mpf((dec - remn) / 256)
            temp = hex(int(remn))
            if len(temp) == 3:
                temp = '0' + temp[-1]
            else:
                temp = temp[2:]
            out = temp + out

            return (out)

        dec = base58_to_dec(addr)
        out = dec_to_byte(dec)
            return (out)
```

Comment: Please give a sample input together with it's expected output!

Comment: BTC wallet-1E9veg1Lo5EgWUcutojCR3eQckrttRaME

Comment: hex wallet result  027cdb92f6e8b3011166a3f3c1be051c19f07fc0

Answer (score -1):

because you are not writing anything to the file and your code is not formatted correctly.

```
import base58


def base58_to_dec(addr):
    dec = 0
    for i in range(len(addr)):
        dec = int(dec * 58 + b58.index(addr[i]))
        return(dec)

def dec_to_byte(dec):
    out = ''
    while dec != 0:
        remn = mpf(dec % 256)
        dec = mpf((dec - remn) / 256)
        temp = hex(int(remn))
        if len(temp) == 3:
            temp = '0' + temp[-1]
        else:
            temp = temp[2:]
        out = temp + out

        return (out)

def decode(addr):

    b58 = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    dec = base58_to_dec(addr)
    out = dec_to_byte(dec)
    return (out)

with open('addresses.txt', 'r') as f, \
     open('RIPEMD160.txt', 'a') as i:
    for addr in f:
        addr = base58.b58decode_check(addr).encode('hex')[2:]
        ads = decode(addr)
        i.write(ads)
    i.close()
```

Comment: i do not understand what you doing but i answered the question about not writing and fixed indent error

Comment: ERROR addr = base58.b58decode_check(addr).encode('hex')[2:]
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @kamburishka your variable addr has bytes not base58 string, check addresses.txt to see if there is bitcoin addresses then add a line with `print(addr)` after the **for** statement to see if addr is a string.

Answer (score -1):

The process of generating bitcoin address is like this

```
public_key=>sha256(sha256(public_key))=>RIPEMD160_address=>base58_address
```

so there is no need for other procedures but simply reverse `base58` to `rmd160` like below

```
import base58

i =open('RIPEMD160.txt', 'a') #open file with append mode on

with open('addresses.txt', 'r') as f:#open files with addresses
    for addr in f:
        addr = addr.strip()#remove trailing space and newline character
        rmd160 = base58.b58decode_check(str(addr)).encode('hex')[2:]#notice str forcing addr to be a string
        i.write(rmd160+"\n")
    i.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: still throws an error line 8, in <module>
  rmd160 = base58.b58decode_check(str(addr)).encode('hex')[2:]#notice str forcing addr to be a string
tributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: i used only one line from this code and it works, see

Comment: `rmd160 = base58.b58decode_check('1E9veg1Lo5EgWUcutojCR3eQckrttRaME').encode('hex')[2:]
print(rmd160)`

Comment: Thanks to everyone, here is the correct code, I corrected it at the top at the beginning.,Run like this **python h160.py address_list.txt 160h_list.txt**

Comment: @Alexiopuk2sefu
`>>> import base58
>>> rmd = base58.b58decode_check('1E9veg1Lo5EgWUcutojCR3eQckrttRaME').encode('hex')[2:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'. Did you mean: 'decode'?`

Comment: @Alexiopuk2sefu The below will work, yours doesn't as you can see in my comment above.
`import base58
print(base58.b58decode_check("1E9veg1Lo5EgWUcutojCR3eQckrttRaME")[1:].hex())`